# Filter paginated posts by date introduced by user (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, input, blogs

I have the post_controller with index method like this:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

and in app / views / posts / index.html.erb i have:

```
.
.
.
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Post</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.user.id %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
      <td><%= post.created_at %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %></td>
      <% if can? :update, post %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
      <% end %>

      <% if can? :destroy, post %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>

  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
</table>
```

So i want a field in this view, where an user can input a date and the view shows all posts wich were created on that date onwards. (Posts date > date_by_user). I tried with "where" method but i couldnt. I dont want to use any gem. So, what is the best and simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can search records in index method like below.

```
date_to_search = Date.parse('2015/1/1')
Post.where(
  'created_at>=? and created_at<=?', 
  date_to_search.beginning_of_day
)
```

created_at is saved as UTC in rails, so you need to specify datetime. Not only date, to get correct data in your local time.